# Pythonic way to get the union of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a better/pythonic way to do the following:

I have a function that merges dictionaries:

```
def merge_dicts(a, *dict_args):
    for dictionary in dict_args:
        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            if k not in a:
                a[k] = v

    return a
```

Here is a sample run:

```
a = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
b = {'B': 3, 'C': 4}
c = merge_dicts(a, b) # {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 4}
```

I am using python2.7.

Comment: What is your definition of merge? which B gets priority?

Comment: If the key already exists on the earlier dictionary, then it won't be overwritten by a same key with a different value. In other words, B from dict a gets priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `update`. Since the earlier dicts have priority you have to update in reverse order, and update with `a` last:

```
def merge_dicts(a, *dict_args):
    d = {}
    for dictionary in reversed(dict_args):
        d.update(dictionary)
    d.update(a)
    return d
```

Or as a one-liner, using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

def merge_dicts(a, *dict_args):
    # chain (key, value) items in order of increasing priority
    return dict(chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in dict_args[::-1]+(a,)))

> merge_dicts(a, b)
{'A': 1, 'C': 4, 'B': 2}
```

If I may add, why not remove `a` from the function signature altogether:

```
def merge_dicts(*dict_args):
    return dict(chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in dict_args[::-1]))
# If you provide 0 or 1 dict,
# this will return an empty dict or the single dict (a copy thereof) itself
```

Comment: You could use `chain.from_iterable(...)`. Instead of `chain(*...)`.

Comment: @DanD. I always wonder which of the two is better / more readable. I tend to go with the shorter one that I am also used to. Is there an inherent advantage to `chain.from_iterable`? **Edit:** I guess, for `chain(*...)` it has to create a `tuple` from the generator. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check the existence of keys in dictionaries, since you want to preserve the first key you can use a dict comprehension by looping through the list of dictionaries backward:

```
{k: v for d in list_of_dict[::-1] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Python will replace the existence keys with new ones, each time it encounter a duplicate one, and since you are looping through the list backward, it will comes up with the first keys in your aggregated dictionary.

Based on your example:

```
>>> {k: v for d in l[::-1] for k, v in d.items()}
{'A': 1, 'C': 4, 'B': 2}
```